# Android or Phonegap skip main page at restart or second launch of the app

Tags: java, javascript, android, eclipse, cordova

I'm developing a mobile app with a main menu where you have to choose from 4 options.
I want to restrict the user so he can choose only the first time when he launch the app.
So the second time when he launches the app, the main page should be skipped and the user should be directed at his option. 
Could you please tell me if exists such functions for Android either in phonegap or java?
Thanks!